# Class 'Crocodicstudio\Cbmodel\CBModelServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, composer-php

Hi i've got problem with app, when I run composer install on s390x Ubuntu I've got error:

```
Class 'Crocodicstudio\Cbmodel\CBModelServiceProvider' not found
```

I've deleted vendor folder and files in cache folder and it doesn't help. Also i've tried this steps and run composer dump-autoload. But it still doesn't help. Please help.
[image: Scr of error]